# We couldn’t create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, formatting, window, windows-installation

Last time I had installed chromium os. Now I wanted to install windows again.

During installation I get the following error:

[image]

I searched a lot and lots of people fixed this issue by removing extra hdd or pendrive. I tried lots of option but I am stuck on this since yesterday.

My Sony laptop is 5 years old, so it does not have UEFI, GPT, secure boot etc.

It does not have cd drive so pen drive is the only option to install os.

I created my 50 gb partition as follow:

```
select disk 0
clean
convert mbr
create partition primary size=51200
format fs=ntfs quick
active
assign letter=C
```

Here is the setupact.log file content:

```
2016-02-07 09:37:39, Info       [0x0a0035] UI     Allowing Page 'Install Type' to be shown
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info       [0x0a0035] UI     Allowing Page 'Install Type' to be shown
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info       [0x0a0047] UI     DiskPart = 0x1
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    Callback_ValidateInstallDrive:====== Does disk [0] offset [0x100000] meet installation reqs? ======
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info       [0x0601ba] IBS    DiskSpaceReqs: Windows image size (from metadata) = [5247493872] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info       [0x0601bb] IBS    DiskSpaceReqs: Windows image size (after padding) = [6309114171] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    DiskSpaceReqs: Windows image contents: [6309114171] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    DiskSpaceReqs: ~BT volume (estimate): [0] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    DiskSpaceReqs: Install volume (estimate): [6309114171] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    DiskSpaceReqs: ~LS volume (estimate w/o padding): [0] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    CalculatingRecommendedSpaceForWindows: RequiredSize  [6309114171] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    CalculatingRecommendedSpaceForWindows: Recommending  [11327598907] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    Callback_ValidateInstallDrive:Install volume -- required    free space = [6309114171] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    Callback_ValidateInstallDrive:Install volume -- recommended free space = [11327598907] bytes
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    Callback_ValidateInstallDrive:Summary - CCP check passed; able to calculate space reqs; able to find install location; location type meets installation reqs; size of location is not too small; location free space is enough; location free space meets the recommendation
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBS    Callback_ValidateInstallDrive:-----------------------------------------------------------
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info       [0x0606cc] IBS    GetSystemDiskNTPath: Unable to get required buffer size for system disk from BCD APIs; status = 0xc0000452
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Error      [0x06069e] IBS    GetMachineInfo:Couldn't find boot disk on this BIOS-based computer
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB CanBeSystemVolume: Volume at disk [0] offset [0x100000] doesn't meet criteria for system volumes...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [0] is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for disk 0: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is not the computer's boot disk.
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB CanBeSystemVolume: Volume at disk [0] offset [0x0] doesn't meet criteria for system volumes...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [0] is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for disk 0: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is not the computer's boot disk.
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Region on disk [0] (offset = [0x0]) is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for {disk 0 offset 0x0}: CanBeSystemVolume] The partition is too small.
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB CanBeSystemVolume: Volume at disk [0] offset [0x7e00] doesn't meet criteria for system volumes...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [0] is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for disk 0: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is not the computer's boot disk.
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Region on disk [0] (offset = [0x7e00]) is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for {disk 0 offset 0x7e00}: CanBeSystemVolume] The partition is too small.
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB CanBeSystemVolume: Volume at disk [0] offset [0xc80100000] doesn't meet criteria for system volumes...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [0] is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:40, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for disk 0: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is not the computer's boot disk.
2016-02-07 09:37:41, Info                  IBSLIB CanBeSystemVolume: Volume at disk [0] offset [0x100000] doesn't meet criteria for system volumes...
2016-02-07 09:37:41, Info                  IBSLIB DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [0] is BLOCKED against capability [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons...
2016-02-07 09:37:41, Info                  IBSLIB LogReasons: [BLOCKING reason for disk 0: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is not the computer's boot disk.
2016-02-07 09:37:41, Info                  IBSLIB Remedy was applied for said disk rule
2016-02-07 09:37:41, Info       [0x0a0035] UI     Allowing Page 'Install Type' to be shown
```

Log is so confusing that I am not able to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had this happen to me once before. The solution on that machine was to edit the boot order of the BIOS, so that the hard drive was the first boot option (In fact, if I remember rightly I moved the USB device to the very last option in the boot order priorities). After saving that, I booted from the USB by pressing F10 (motherboard specific) and doing it as a one-time boot.

Now, whether that's the problem for you, I'm not entirely sure. The error you're getting is:

> [BLOCKING reason for disk 0: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is
> not the computer's boot disk.

making me suspect that Windows isn't reading the drive as your boot disk, instead it's picking up your USB device as such.

There is another suggestion on [this forum thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/179807-couldnt-find-boot-disk-error-while-installing-windows-7-using-usb.html) where they had same problem. The steps [someone took to resolve it](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/179807-couldnt-find-boot-disk-error-while-installing-windows-7-using-usb-post1527663.html#post1527663) were to copy and run the installer from the hard drive and run it from there:

> 1. Booted from the USB installer and pressed SHIFT+F10
> 2. Executed the "clean" command in diskpart
> 3. Created a 5 GB fat32 partition and assigned a drive letter using "assign" command
> 4. Copied the usb flash drive contents into the newly formed partition using xcopy
> 5. Rebooted the system with the 5gb partition in my HDD as the boot location

Hopefully one of these is a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks a million. I was trying it for last 10 hours!. I know my hdd is missing boot sector, and I was trying to create with xcopy. You are right, I just copied my pen drive to C drive with x copy and now system had started installing windows 10 without usb!

Comment: Although above method will create issue when I again format C drive. This will also wipe boot record. Now I understand that even my bios was set to boot from internal hdd, usb installation thinks that my boot record is stored  on USB, which I cannot remove while installing it!. I thought using external CD drive will help, and YES, using external CD drive, windows installation had created 500 MB boot partition before it starts installation. This is my final finding and perfect solution. Hope it helps some one. Ubuntu installation is way better when partitioning hdd!

Comment: Changing the boot order did it for me